# whats the best cli tool for mysql process view?

Tags: mysql

whats the best cli tool for mysql process view, what updates itself like every second or so. arrow up and return is stupid way as i do it now

````
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST;
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | User            | Host      | db      | Command | Time | State                             | Info                                                                          |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2 | system user     |           |         | Daemon  |    0 | Waiting for event from ndbcluster | NULL                                                                          |
|  6 | event_scheduler | localhost | NULL    | Daemon  | 5293 | Waiting on empty queue            | NULL                                                                          |
| 11 | root            | localhost | NULL    | Query   |    0 | starting                          | SHOW PROCESSLIST                                                              |
| 14 | root            | localhost | database| Query   |    2 | update                            | INSERT INTO `Table_i_watch` VALUES (727353,11986,NULL,9886,'data_im_inserting |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST;
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | User            | Host      | db      | Command | Time | State                             | Info                                                                          |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2 | system user     |           |         | Daemon  |    0 | Waiting for event from ndbcluster | NULL                                                                          |
|  6 | event_scheduler | localhost | NULL    | Daemon  | 5294 | Waiting on empty queue            | NULL                                                                          |
| 11 | root            | localhost | NULL    | Query   |    0 | starting                          | SHOW PROCESSLIST                                                              |
| 14 | root            | localhost | database| Query   |    3 | update                            | INSERT INTO `Table_i_watch` VALUES (727353,11986,NULL,9886,'data_im_inserting |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST;
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | User            | Host      | db      | Command | Time | State                             | Info                                                                          |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2 | system user     |           |         | Daemon  |    0 | Waiting for event from ndbcluster | NULL                                                                          |
|  6 | event_scheduler | localhost | NULL    | Daemon  | 5295 | Waiting on empty queue            | NULL                                                                          |
| 11 | root            | localhost | NULL    | Query   |    0 | starting                          | SHOW PROCESSLIST                                                              |
| 14 | root            | localhost | database| Query   |    4 | update                            | INSERT INTO `Table_i_watch` VALUES (727353,11986,NULL,9886,'data_im_inserting |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)```
````

Comment: If using a shell script, consider piping it to `grep -v Sleep` because sleeping connections are just "in the way".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `watch` utility that way:

```
watch -n 5 "mysql -u user -ppass -e 'SHOW PROCESSLIST;' | egrep -iv 'sleep|daemon'"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use terminal you can create a procedure.
It gives the starting time and end time of execution and sleeps 5 seconds and re-execute again until row count 1000

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE processlist()    
BEGIN
declare start_query datetime default null;
declare end_query datetime default null;
main: REPEAT
  SELECT now() INTO start_query;
  set @insert = "show processlist"; 
  SELECT SLEEP(5); 
  SELECT now() INTO end_query;
  SELECT start_query,end_query; 
  PREPARE QUERY FROM @insert ;
  EXECUTE QUERY;
  UNTIL row_count() = 1000 END REPEAT main; 
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

If you want CLI check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074641/get-mysql-processlist-log-every-5-seconds

Answer (score 1):

Use not CLI but [mysqladmin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqladmin.html).

```sh
mysqladmin --user=username --password=userpassword --sleep=1 processlist
```